# Auto copy current tab URL

Tags: javascript, clipboarddata

I have been using this code to copy the current active tab URL on clipboard.

```
function autocopy() {
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
            var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
            document.body.appendChild(dummy);
            dummy.value = location.href;
            dummy.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(dummy);
        });
})();
```

but i want it to be automatically be able the url to clipboard so i dont have to click anywhere, but its not working.....

```
    function autocopy() {
                var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
                document.body.appendChild(dummy);
                dummy.value = location.href;
                dummy.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                document.body.removeChild(dummy);
             };
    window.onload = autocopy();
```

Comment: What does it copy ?

Comment: That's because you can't and shouldn't. Imagine you have something important on your clipboard and then you visit a website that just overwrites it without your permission!

Comment: Take a look here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard`outside of a `click` event you are required request permission to access the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

using this code you can copy url of the current tab

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(location.href)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("done");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

if you want to copy from the input field

```
let i = document.querySelector("#input");

navigator.clipboard.writeText(i)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("done");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

Comment: using it in tampermonkey.....create a window.onload function for the upper code .....not working....